VDOM as design pattern in any kind of application
can we consider VDOM as something like a design pattern ?
in any kind of application that UI/Document will gets updated constantly
for example in an TUI editor, like vim, joe, and ...
UI will be the terminals screen, and that's like an array of cells that we can change them
in react VDOM is in browser and a tree of elements . right ?
so every time that a pixel changed, we can detect and just update that area, instead of updating whole screen
in fact i mean simulating the screen (or our UI, or what ever that can call it) with a proper data structure
Is there anything similar that I can read about?
i was learning about editors, and react
and i want to know if we can have something like VDOM to create our editor
